# Creating a websocket server on Linux

Tags: c#, linux

I want to create a websocket server and I've found a great article [here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server). However C# will output an exe file.

I'd like to have it run on a linux box. What I want to do is to connect to the server, and when something happens on the filesystem to retrieve a message from the server (using the `FileSystemWatcher` on Windows or the `iNotify` daemon on linux) and the program will run the corresponding code.

So, how can such daemon for linux (in C#) or any other way to achieve this?

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, hence the comment.  For C# on Linux, take a look at mono.

Comment: @BenBurns I am aware of Mono, but I don't know if it would work in a server environment (so no gui, while in C# it would be a console application).

Comment: Mono works fine for CLI apps.  Depending on your distro however, you may need a custom build which doesn't require X11, as some package managers might be dumb and try to pull down X when you install mono.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're really requiring C# on linux (which isn't really wise and forces you to use mono).

There are other great ways to manage websockets on a linux server. For example node.js, [java](http://jwebsocket.org/)(not personally tested)  or my favorite : [go](http://go.hokapoka.com/golang/web-chat-using-websockets-and-go-link/).

Comment: Hmm thanks, can it also check if the filesystem has been changed? I don't think it can and I might be forced to use C# or any other "real" language.

Comment: I'm not familiar with inotify in Go but this may be what you need : http://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#InotifyAddWatch. By the way I don't see in what C# is more "real" than Go (or another language).

Comment: true, C# is just another language - and a 2nd class one on Linux. Linux's API for getting filesystem changes is called inotify http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-ubuntu-inotify/.

Comment: @Devator, use Mono (it's free port .NET (and C# so) on Linux)

Answer (score 1):

I develop a WebSocket component named [WebSocketListener](http://vtortola.github.io/WebSocketListener/) that supports Mono. Take a look on [this guide about how to make it work with Mono](https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketListener/wiki/Mono-support).